# Web page displays on Host ie11 but not on another machine, have I missed something?

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-11

i have an asp.net web site made to simply allow people to update some sqlserver tables.

The website works perfectly on the host server in Edge and IE11.

On other machines when accessing the server like so :
http://server.net/8081/homepage.aspx

It works in Chrome and Edge.
however in IE11 it displays wrong. Some colours come across, all gridviews appear correctly but layout is literally bonkers.

Is there something simple i am missing? This is my first time publishing a site in asp.net. all help appreciated.

Comment: Try to provide screenshot of correct and incorrect output. It can help us to understand the issue. It can be a CSS related or any other issue. To narrow down the issue, you can compare the settings of IE 11 browser on both server and your client machine may give some idea. If there is any sample code which can produce the issue than kindly provide us to make a test.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT, at the moment, by adding this to my pages it has resolved my issue but i guess this is more of a work around rather than a correct fix.  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

Comment: I think it is a correct fix for your issue. If you still thinks that there may be other solutions for the issue than you need to post your sample code. We will try to check it to find any other possible solutions. You can also try to post this solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.